# Eclipse including multiple jars from apache ivy IDE plugin in web deployment assembly

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, ivy, ivyde

I recently updated my project setting to resolve a resource problem between my groovy plugin and ivy plugin.

I use apache ivy IDE plugin 2.2.0 final & eclipse Helios Service Release 1 on a 64bit machine.

Before I did:
project -> right click on ivy plugin -> properties -> Advanced:

Enable project specific settings

Build the classpath with:

retrieved artifacts

Retrieve pattern: WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]

Delete old retrieved artifacts [checked]


This works for me except when I also have groovy plugin in my project, the groovy project will hold on to the jars copied to WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ and I wouldn't be allowed to delete any of the jars in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ until I restart eclipse

Now I removed that ivy plugin setting
Added my ivy plugin as a deployment assembly
The problem I'm running into now is that whenever I publish to tomcat using eclipse, it would copy over **TWO jars per some of my ivy entries**.  One of the jars is always the latest version, then the other jar seems to be a random earlier version of the same jar.  However the problem is resolved once I switch back to the old way of copying jars using the ivy plugin.

I cannot figure out if this new problem is a ivy plugin issue or a eclipse deployment assembly issue. Others at work have tried by doing the same thing in the same project and they do not have the **TWO jars** problem.

Have anyone else run into this problem before and have a solution for it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ant with Ivy?
Then, you could define an Ant task for copying the Jars:

```
<copy todir="@{target-dir}">
    <fileset dir="@{source-dir}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

You can specify the fileset even in a more detailed way.
Some examples from my Ant build file:

```
<fileset dir="...">
    <include name="${ivy.module}-${ivy.revision}-jar.jar" />
    <include name="${ivy.module}-test-unit-${ivy.revision}-jar.jar" />
    <include name="lib/*.jar" />
    <include name="lib-tests/*.jar" />
    <exclude name="**/*.java" />
    <exclude name="**/*.class" />
</fileset>
```